# Access data without token Django simple_jwt lib

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using django simple_jwt library with DRF for a React project. Everything is working well except I cannot access any data (even simple GET requests) if no access token is provided. I didn't find a way to do it in the docs , is there some kind of decorator, setting to allow simple requests without an access token? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access apis without token , make them `public`. By default all the api requests are required to be `authenticated` in your case currently.

Sample:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class ExampleApi(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    authentication_classes = []
```

Comment: full answer was here, could not find it in Stack Overflow research engine 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375706/django-rest-framework-avoid-authentication-jwt

Comment: I do not know your source code so didn't provide any code suggestions, updated the answer for generic APIView.

Comment: Had already accepted you answer mate. Thanks